# NullPointerException extraño en método onClick

Tags: java, android

He estado peleándome con este error que no entiendo por varios días, ya estuve investigando pero no encuentro nada al respecto y el log no da muchos detalles sobre el error o si los da no entiendo. Esto es lo que sucede:

Tengo un `FloatingACtionButton` que al presionar realiza una acción en servidor, sin embargo ya probé dejar simplemente un mensaje de Log cuando el botón es presionado, lo extraño es que me lanza un `NullPointerException` que no entiendo y lo peor es que el error no he logrado reproducirlo con claridad, al principio pensé que era completamente aleatorio pero me di cuenta que solo se da en las compilaciones de tipo release (es decir ya firmadas) y que tienen el proguard activo, sin embargo el error no se produce siempre, igual varía y no tengo claro que lo ocasiona. El código de mi `FloatingActionButton` es el siguiente:

```
public class MyActivity extends AppConpatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {  
  private FloatingActionButton mFab;  
  @Override  
  protected void onCreate(Bundle saved InstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    ....  
    mFab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.my_fab);  
    mFab.setOnClickListener(this);  
    .....  
  }  
  @Override  
  public void onClick(View v) {  
    switch(v.getId()) {  
      case R.id.my_fab:  
        Log.d("Test", "FAB pressed");  
        break;  
      default:  
        Log.e("Test", "unknow id");  
        break;  
    }  
  }  
}
```

El XML no tendría que ser el problema pues me lanzaría un `NullPointerException` en el `onCreate` al intentar hacer el `setOnClickListener` más el `NullPointerException` es en el `onClick` así que el XML no produce el error, pero no se entonces exactamente que es lo que produce el error, la referencia ya la expliqué arriba y es lo poco que he logrado reproducir del error. Mi salida del log es la siguiente:

> java.lang.NullPointerException:
>       at com.example.myapp.MyActivity$2.onClick (MyActivity.java)
>       at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:6205)
>       at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:23653)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:751)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6682)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1520)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1410)

Aclaro que el mensaje de log dentro del `switch` jamás es impreso así que no detecta ni siquiera el default, de antemano agradezco a quien pueda ayudarme o dar un poco de luz a esto que ya me trae de cabeza.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el XML correspondiente a ese FloatingActionButton?

Answer (score 3):

Pueden ser dos las causas:

**I)** Revisa el archivo .xml que carga tu `Activity` mediante `setContentView()` (esto dentro de `onCreate()`), dentro de este layout .xml no existe el elemento con id `my_fab` que sería tu `FloatingActionButton`, si no existe la referencia no puede llamar el método `onClick()`

**II)** Si existe el `FloatingActionButton`  con id `my_fab` dentro del .xml , asegura no debe tener la propiedad `android:onClick` ya que tiene implementado su propio listener dentro del código.